# What is the value of $ \int\frac{ r^2e^{-r'}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|} d^3r'$?

Tags: integration, vectors

How do I find  $ \int\frac{ r^2e^{-r'}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|} d^3r'$

For context it is to calculate the potential $\int\frac{n(\vec{r})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|}d^3r'$ When the density $n$ is an exponential function

Comment: If it's meant to be a triple integral, what does $e^{-x}$ mean? Or have you proven a triple integral of interest is proportional to a single integral, such as $\int_0^\infty\frac{2xe^{-x}dx}{|a-x|}$?

Comment: Wait, so is it meant to be $r^2\int\frac{e^{-r^\prime}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}^\prime|}d^3\vec{r}^\prime$? If so, the substitution $\vec{u}:=\vec{r}^\prime-\vec{r}$ will help.